# Regex for less than $250

Tags: regex, numbers, dollar-sign

I am brand new to regex and I am looking for a way to match any dollar amount under $250. How can this be accomplished? There is a dollar symbol in the numbers that I will be looking at. Thank you!

Comment: A regex is probably *NOT* the best way to "evaluate a number".  Although it can be a GREAT way to deal with the "$" character in your input.  Q: Is this part of some application you're coding?  What language are you using?  Implicit question: can't you just convert the input to a number?

Comment: Is there a reason you're asking specifically about regex, could you give more context to the use case perhaps?

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: The software I am using only uses regex. I need to identify certain customers based on a field on their profiles in order to message them.

Answer (score 1):

Using regexp:

```js
const pattern = /^\$(1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d)$/

console.log('--- edge cases ---')
console.log("$250", pattern.test("$250"))
console.log("$255", pattern.test("$255"))
console.log("$269", pattern.test("$269"))
console.log("$420", pattern.test("$420"))
console.log("$249", pattern.test("$249"))
console.log("$199", pattern.test("$199"))
console.log(" $55", pattern.test("$55"))
console.log("  $0", pattern.test("$0"))
console.log("  $8", pattern.test("$8"))
console.log("  e", pattern.test("e"))
console.log(" 50", pattern.test("50"))
console.log("space", pattern.test(""))

console.log('--- random tests ---')
Array.from({length: 20}, _ => `$${Math.floor(Math.random() * 500)}`)
     .forEach(e => console.log(e.padStart(4), pattern.test(e)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Using non-regexp approach (better one I my opinion), pseudo code in javascript:

```js
const test = str => str?.split('$')?.[1] < 250

console.log('$350', test('$350'))
console.log('$250', test('$250'))
console.log('$50', test('$50'))
console.log('$249', test('$249'))
console.log('$199', test('$199'))
console.log('420', test('420'))
console.log('space', test(' '))
console.log('empty', test(''))
console.log('undefined', test())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```